# Reduce Azure SQL Database Size

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm doing my best an deleting rows and rebuilding indexes but the size of the database is growing really fast and I can't see the effect of my operations.

Is there a cause for this and is there a way to reduce the size of the database other than row deletion and index rebuild?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Please run the following special store procedure and let us know which database file is getting bigger.

```
sp_helpfile
```

If the log file is getting bigger, please run below statement to recover space log.

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (log, 0)
```

If the data file, and not the log file, is increasing in size use below query to know which tables are consuming the most space, and start to investigate from there.

```
select 
    o.name, 
    max(s.row_count) AS 'Rows',
    sum(s.reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / (1024 * 1024) as 'GB',
    (8 * 1024 * sum(s.reserved_page_count)) / (max(s.row_count)) as 'Bytes/Row'
from sys.dm_db_partition_stats s, sys.objects o
where o.object_id = s.object_id
group by o.name
having max(s.row_count) > 0
order by GB desc
```

Below query gives you the size of every index also.

```
select  
    o.Name,
    i.Name,
    max(s.row_count) AS 'Rows',
    sum(s.reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / (1024 * 1024) as 'GB',
    (8 * 1024* sum(s.reserved_page_count)) / max(s.row_count) as 'Bytes/Row'
from 
    sys.dm_db_partition_stats s, 
    sys.indexes i, 
    sys.objects o
where 
    s.object_id = i.object_id
    and s.index_id = i.index_id
    and s.index_id >0
    and i.object_id = o.object_id
group by i.Name, o.Name
having SUM(s.row_count) > 0
order by GB desc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the database log is merely 1 GB while the database mdf is larger than 800GB

Comment: I added a query that tells you the top tables consuming more space. From there you can then investigate why those tables are consuming such space.

Answer (score 14):

Check out this Microsoft Post..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-file-space-management#reclaim-unused-allocated-space

Reclaim unused allocated space
DBCC shrink
Once databases have been identified for reclaiming unused allocated space, modify the name of the database in the following command to shrink the data files for each database.

SQL

-- Shrink database data space allocated.

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (N'db1')
```

SHRINKFILE was not working for me on Azure SQL

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://aboutsqlserver.com/2014/12/02/size-does-matter-10-ways-to-reduce-the-database-size-and-improve-performance-in-sql-server/) references a few strategies to cope with large databases.