# Why the row size is very big?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a table named Alerta in a sql database (Azure) that has three columns, two floating type (float) and one datetime type column, the problem is that the database is filling up very fast and I have searched for a solution and I found that could be the size of the table in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829322/reduce-azure-sql-database-size/45830080)

I executed the following code and I could see that the bytes per row of the Alerta table is 27411 bytes

This is the code I executed to determine the bytes/row:

```
select 
o.name, 
max(s.row_count) AS 'Rows',
sum(s.reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / (1024 * 1024) as 'GB',
(8 * 1024 * sum(s.reserved_page_count)) / (max(s.row_count)) as 'Bytes/Row'
from sys.dm_db_partition_stats s, sys.objects o
where o.object_id = s.object_id
group by o.name
having max(s.row_count) > 0
order by GB desc
```

This is the design of the table; this table has no index, not even primary key

[image: design of the table]

I also executed the query of that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829322/reduce-azure-sql-database-size/45830080) to determine the size per index and this are the [results](https://mega.nz/#!BZAjlCCJ!NHgebscHluMsR5VcS7pDeSFlev42kIO60IZOEXXqFCE).

I am confused because the table only has three columns and I haven´t found a solution to reduce the row size of the table

Comment: show us your table structure. Sql query may give you insight but not to us

Comment: Given that your table is two floats and a datetime, that seems odd to me. But, how many indexes do you have on the table? You can get per index usage with that same DMV since index_id is represented there. I'd also be interested in what your data mutations look like on that table. That is, how is data inserted? How is it updated? Either (or both) of those can have an impact on index fragmentation (which I'd also be interested in knowing what that looks like for that specific table).

Comment: @BenThul The data is inserted via Stream analytics job of Azure, the data is inserted every four seconds and the table doesn't have any indexes.

Comment: The "how" question was less in relation to specific technologies involved but more "how is the data being inserted with respect to any relevant indexes?". Since you've stated that the table doesn't have any indexes, you're inserting into a heap. Does data get updated after insertion? How do deletes happen? At the very least, I'd strongly suggest putting a clustered index on your table. Heaps are good for some things, but ongoing data access into them is not great. Any word on the fragmentation for that table?

Comment: @BenThul Hi, I did a query to check the index fragmentation and the heap had less than six percent of fragmentation, but I did that You said, I created a clustered index and the problem was solved, but I don't know why... Can You explain me the reason, please?

Answer (score 0):

The allowable maximum row size is 8060 bytes in SQL server(Azure), but the result you get after executed your code is that the bytes per row of the Alerta table is 27411 bytes.
[image]

I think you can try the following [script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25531/how-can-i-get-the-actual-data-size-per-row-in-a-sql-server-table) to get the per row size agian:

```
declare @table nvarchar(128)
declare @idcol nvarchar(128)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

--initialize those two values
set @table = 'YourTable'
set @idcol = 'some id to recognize the row'

set @sql = 'select ' + @idcol +' , (0'

select @sql = @sql + ' + isnull(datalength(' + name + '), 1)' 
        from  sys.columns 
        where object_id = object_id(@table)
        and   is_computed = 0
set @sql = @sql + ') as rowsize from ' + @table + ' order by rowsize desc'

PRINT @sql

exec (@sql)
```

Compare the result to your result. For example, I created a table and run the script by SSMS:

```
select * , (0 + isnull(datalength(price), 1) + isnull(datalength(money), 1) + isnull(datalength(date), 1)) as rowsize from test order by rowsize desc
```

[image]

Hope this can helps you.