# Azure Database cannot reduce the sizing

Tags: azure-sql-database

Azure Database cannot reduce the sizing from 750 to 500 GB.

Overall sizing after I checked in the Azure dashboard.

- Used space is 248.29 GB.
- Allocated space is 500.02 GB
- Maximum storage size is 750 GB.

The validation message when I reduce the sizing:

Message is

> The storage size of your database cannot be smaller than the currently
>   allocated size. To reduce the database size, the database first needs
>   to reclaim unused space by running DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (XXX_Database
>   Name). This operation can impact performance while it is running and
>   may take several hours to complete.

What should I do?

Best Regard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829322/reduce-azure-sql-database-size

Comment: How are you reducing the sizing? Show us the query

Answer (score 1):

If we want to reduce the database size, we need to ensure the number of databse size is larger than the number of the `Allocated space` you set. Now, according to your need, we should reclaim unused allocated space. Regarding how to do it, we can run the following command

```
-- Shrink database data space allocated.
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (N'db1')
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-file-space-management#reclaim-unused-allocated-space)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error via CLI after also disabling read scale and the solution was to remove --max-size 250GB from command:

```
az sql db update -g groupname -s servername -n dbname --edition GeneralPurpose --capacity 1 --max-size 250GB --family Gen5 --compute-model Serverless --no-wait
```