# Azure SQL db with no data takes too much space

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I set up azure sql database in free tier for testing purposes. It has 32 MB limit, but it should be fine, since my db is about 30 tables and few rows of data per each (really just for testing purposes).
After some while, I reached 32 MB limit. I was forced to delete (and drop) all the tables. Now the db takes 87.5 % **WITH NO TABLES IN IT**.

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45830080/1154773) about data size investigations and here are the results:

[image]

[image]

(more rows here, but each with 0.1 MB and less)

I tried to run `DBCC SHRINKFILE (log, 0);` but nothing has changed.

I also did `sp_spaceused`

Which resulted in:

[image]

The percentage form azure portal (87.5 %) changes time to time for no reason (sometimes it drops to 37.5 %)

So my question is - what am I doing wrong here? How should I proceed to not have most of the db filled without any data..?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure free tier account type provides 250 GB free storage with S0 instance for 12 months.

[image]

Please create another database (upto 10 databases allowed in free tier) using S0 instance. Refer the steps given by @FabioSipoliMuller in this [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/278750/about-12-months-free-azure-resources.html) to deploy the same.

**Note:** You need to make some changes in configuration while deploying the database in free service.