# azure sql database slowly filling up although data should be staying the same

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am using Azure SQL Database with 10gb of storage (Standard S2: 50 DTUs). I am running a process where I am deleting all rows in a table every 6 hours and recreating and loading table from our business system. What I am noticing is that although the data in our source isn't getting exponentially larger it seems the database is getting larger at a higher speed. I am wondering if azure SQL when dropping and recreating stores even though its deleted and counted against your total storage?

Thanks for any help on this.

[image]

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28360/sql-server-database-size-didnt-decrease-after-deleting-large-number-of-rows

Answer (score 0):

Please defrag all indexes. As mentioned on [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dilkushp/fragmentation-in-sql-azure), fragmentation can claim a lot space.

Run sp_helpfile to verify the log is not consuming space also. If the log is big run the following statement to recover space.

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (log, 0)
```

Consider also to shrink the database.

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (N'db1')
```

On [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829322/reduce-azure-sql-database-size/45830080#45830080) I provided some queries that may be useful about database size.

Answer (score 0):

While what Alberto Morillo says is good I suspect something changed the 13/12/2022:

[image]

The options are two:

1. The stored procedure that is supposed to delete the data is not deleting data or is deleting less data
2. More data are ingested since the 13 of December